# ddrescue: error when resuming rescue

Tags: ddrescue

After running ddrescue `ddrescue /dev/sdb1 /media/lukas/Elements/sdb.dd /home/lukas/sdb.log` to restore a currupted 4TB disk to a file for over a week the computer has been plugged out by accident.
``
If I read the documentation correctly resuming the process is as simple as running the same command with the same logfile and that would go on where it ended.
There is however this error:
`ddrescue: Rescued data in mapfile goes past end of input file. Use '-C' if you are reading from a partial copy.`
I am reading from the whole partition so -C should not apply, right?
did the disc somehow become shorter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I tried to run the same command to new file and new mapfile to compare the two mapfiles and turns out the commands were not identical. Old input file was `\dev\sdb`(whole disc) new input file was `\dev\sdb1` (partition only). Despite there being only the one partition there was some difference from this.

Comment: "Despite there being only the one partition there was some difference from this." – The difference is normal and expected. A partition taking exactly the whole device is technically possible, but very unusual; it would have to contain the partition table and this would make it almost useless if you wanted it to contain anything else (usually we want a filesystem). Therefore any sane setup leaves the partition table outside of any partition. This means any partition (even a solitary big partition) has to be smaller than the whole device.